# Primality test calulating on paper. Specific case

Tags: cryptography, primality-test

How to make primality test on paper without any calculator for high numbers like
$$
    (32^{200}) - 1 
$$

$$
    (400^{555}) - 1
$$
What specific test is useful in such cases: $$(a^b) - 1$$ where a and b are high numbers), Fermat's theorem, AKS or is there any other test that shows that this equation is prime number?

Comment: As long as $a>2$ or $b$ is composite, one can just write down a factor of $a^b-1$.

Comment: ...but even if $a>2$ and $b$ is *prime*, $a^b - 1$ can be composite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a-1$ is a factor of $a^b-1$.  So if $a>2$, then $a^b-1$ is composite.  For the case of $a=2$, you are looking for Mersenne primes.